# Error when running Corda flow tests from IntelliJ

Tags: corda

When I run Corda flow tests from IntelliJ, the tests fail with the following errors:

> QUASAR WARNING: Quasar Java Agent isn't running. If you're using
>   another instrumentation method you can ignore this message; otherwise,
>   please refer to the Getting Started section in the Quasar
>   documentation.

and

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing the '-javaagent' JVM
>   argument. Make sure you run the tests with the Quasar java agent
>   attached to your JVM. See https://docs.corda.net/troubleshooting.html
>   - 'Fiber classes not instrumented' for more details.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Corda flows need to be instrumented using Quasar before they are run, so that they can be suspended mid-execution.

To achieve this in IntelliJ, you need to:

- Create a run config for your tests
- Open the run config and change the VM options to `-ea -javaagent:PATH-TO-QUASAR-JAR`

  - In the CorDapp example and templates, `quasar.jar` is located at `lib/quasar.jar`, so you'd use `-ea -javaagent:../lib/quasar.jar`

Alternatively, you can edit the default JUnit run config to use the Quasar javaagent by default, avoiding you having to do this every time you pick a new test to run.

Comment: Is there a way to include this within gradle or test dependencies? What if we don't want it to be included as a VM argument within our run configs?

Comment: It’ll be added automatically when nodes are run normally. This is only required for tests. There is no way around it currently.

Comment: If you use TestNG you can use a TestNG listener to load it automatically.

Comment: I get stuck on "Starting Gradle Daemo..." and "Test events were not received".

Answer (score 6):

This is a basic error that you get if you don't set Quasar, you need to select your test-> go to Intellij top bar-> Run -> Edit Configurations and then set up like this photo in VM options:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From template readme

> We recommend editing your IntelliJ preferences so that you use the Gradle runner - this means that the quasar utils plugin will make sure that some flags (like -javaagent - see below) are set for you.
>
> To switch to using the Gradle runner:
>
> Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle ->
> Runner (or search for runner) Windows: this is in "Settings" MacOS:
> this is in "Preferences" Set "Delegate IDE build/run actions to
> gradle" to true Set "Run test using:" to "Gradle Test Runner" If you
> would prefer to use the built in IntelliJ JUnit test runner, you can
> run gradlew installQuasar which will copy your quasar JAR file to the
> lib directory. You will then need to specify -javaagent:lib/quasar.jar
> and set the run directory to the project root directory for each test.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, if you face same error in VSCode, you can add

```
"java.test.config": {
    "vmArgs": ["-ea", "-javaagent:../lib/quasar.jar"]
},
```

to `settings.json`. The path `../lib/quasar.jar` may be different in your project.