# Unable to run unit tests in corda 4

Tags: corda

I was running my unit test in corda 4from intellij but getting this error.

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : lib/quasar.jar-Dco.paralleluniverse.fibers.verifyInstrumentation
Error occurred during initialization of VMagent library failed to init: instrument
```

[image: here is my run config]

Comment: This has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411363/error-when-running-corda-flow-tests-from-intellij

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when running Corda flow tests from IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411363/error-when-running-corda-flow-tests-from-intellij)

Answer (score 0):

think the path is probably wrong and it cant find the quasar.jar. Also there should be a space between quasar.jar and -dco.parallel.... Try use an absolute path instead.

Comment: Hey but in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411363/error-when-running-corda-flow-tests-from-intellij it was mentioned this only

Comment: Also, if you've upgraded your project to Corda 4 from Corda 3, make sure you've followed the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/head/app-upgrade-notes.html#step-14-possibly-update-your-checked-in-quasar-jar to update the checked in quasar jar to version 0.7.10.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me also found that is was the wrong path of [lib/quasar.jar] on the what did was point it to the main project path and it worked.
[The full path to the jar in my IDE run config in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdDde.png)