# gradlew clean deployNodes - QUASAR WARNING: Quasar Java Agent isn't running

Tags: intellij-idea, corda, quasar

When I run "gradlew clean deployNodes" or "gradlew deployNodes", I get a warning on Quasar library:
QUASAR WARNING: Quasar Java Agent isn't running. If you're using another instrumentation method you can ignore this message; otherwise, please refer to the Getting
 Started section in the Quasar documentation.

How can i fix this warning ?

I upgraded Corda to 4.1

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411363/error-when-running-corda-flow-tests-from-intellij

Comment: Please do ./gradlew clean build deployNodes

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to double-check the intellij settings.

> Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle ->
>   Runner (or search for runner) Windows: this is in "Settings" MacOS:
>   this is in "Preferences" Set "Delegate IDE build/run actions to
>   gradle" to true Set "Run test using:" to "Gradle Test Runner" If you
>   would prefer to use the built in IntelliJ JUnit test runner, you can
>   run gradlew installQuasar which will copy your quasar JAR file to the
>   lib directory. You will then need to specify -javaagent:lib/quasar.jar
>   and set the run directory to the project root directory for each test.

As mentioned in the comments from manish, make sure to try cleaning the gradle cache as well: ./gradlew clean build deployNodes.

Joel has a good answer for a similar quasar issue on this StackOverflow question: [Error when running Corda flow tests from IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411363/error-when-running-corda-flow-tests-from-intellij)