# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing the '-javaagent' JVM argument. Make sure you run the tests with the Quasar java agent attached to your JVM

Tags: java, blockchain, corda

When trying to run test for CORDA the given Test case getting the following error. I am using JDK 1.8., Intellij IDEA on Windows 10. Even Though I have mentioned the the Quasar.jar in VM options.

RUN >> Edit Configurations >> Junit>> Required Test Class >>VM options:-ea -javaagent:lib\quasar.jar
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go4pl.png)

```
package com.template;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.template.contracts.MetalContract;
import com.template.flows.Responder;
import com.template.states.MetalState;
import net.corda.core.concurrent.CordaFuture;
import net.corda.core.contracts.Command;
import net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState;
import net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction;
import net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork;
import net.corda.testing.node.MockNetworkParameters;
import net.corda.testing.node.StartedMockNode;
import net.corda.testing.node.TestCordapp;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.template.flows.IssueMetal;
import com.template.flows.TransferMetal;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue;

public class FlowTests {
    private final MockNetwork network = new MockNetwork(new MockNetworkParameters(ImmutableList.of(
        TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.template.contracts"),
        TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.template.flows")
    )));

    private final StartedMockNode Mint = network.createNode();
    private final StartedMockNode A = network.createNode();
    private final StartedMockNode B = network.createNode();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        network.runNetwork();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        network.stopNodes();
    }

    // ------------------------------------------ Issue Metal Flow Tests ----------------------------------------

    @Test
    public void transactionHasNoInputsHasOneMetalStateOutputWithTheCorrectOwner() throws Exception {

        IssueMetal flow = new IssueMetal("Gold", 10, A.getInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0));
        CordaFuture<SignedTransaction> future = Mint.startFlow(flow);
        setup();
        SignedTransaction signedTransaction = future.get();

        assertEquals (0, signedTransaction.getTx().getInputs().size());

        assertEquals (1, signedTransaction.getTx().getOutputStates().size());
        MetalState output = signedTransaction.getTx().outputsOfType(MetalState.class).get(0);

        assertEquals(A.getInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0), output.getOwner());

    }
}
```

The Error is :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing the '-javaagent' JVM argument. Make sure you run the tests with the Quasar java agent attached to your JVM.
See https://docs.corda.net/head/testing.html#running-tests-in-intellij - 'Fiber classes not instrumented' for more details.

    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.checkQuasarJavaAgentPresence(SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.kt:317)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.start(SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.kt:135)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$8.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:409)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$8.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:122)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:268)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:237)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:254)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:388)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode.start(InternalMockNetwork.kt:346)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNodeImpl(InternalMockNetwork.kt:471)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:449)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:444)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNotaries$node_driver(InternalMockNetwork.kt:253)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:236)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:149)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:305)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:294)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:303)
    at com.template.FlowTests.<init>(FlowTests.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:64)
```

Comment: Visit Below link for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411363/error-when-running-corda-flow-tests-from-intellij

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when running Corda flow tests from IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411363/error-when-running-corda-flow-tests-from-intellij)

Comment: I tried that it is attached in the Photo link but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Gradle Test Runner so that you don't have to set the `javaagent` flag manually.

To use Gradle Test Runner Click the Run/Debug configuration drop down > `Edit Configurations...` > `+` > `Gradle` In the form that appears, fill in the details:

`Gradle-Project` : [path to your project]

`Task`: :cleanTest :test

`Arguments`: --tests ""

Reference below:
[image]